# Conditionally insert, update or remove document

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$document = $client->$db->$collection->findAndModify(
  [ $field => $value ], // query
  ['$set' => $updatedDocument], // update
  null, // only return these fields
  [
    "sort" => [], 
    "remove" => false, 
    "update" => [], // array for update? not sure what this does!
    "new" => false, 
    "upsert" => false 
  ]
);
```

With that [syntax for the PHP Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findandmodify.php), is it possible to conditionally `insert`, `update` or `remove` a document without making additional queries to the DB?

For example:

```
$document = $client->$db->$collection->findAndModify(
  [ $field => $value ], // query
  // if $document != $newDocument: update
  ['$set' => $updatedDocument],
  null, // only return these fields
  [
    "sort" => [], 
    // if $document != $certainCondition: remove
    "remove" => true,
    "update" => [], 
    // if $document does not exist: insert (or upsert?)
    "new" => false,
    // if $document does not exist: upsert?
    "upsert" => false 
  ]
);
```

Comment: The `options` should be a keyed array. Like `["update" => [...]]`

Comment: @jszobody ah thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) can only update or remove the found document. If you set remove flag to true and set update fields to something non-empty at the same time, the document is going to be found, updated and then deleted. It does not matter what driver you use, that's how mongodb is built.

You will have to use plain update and remove.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see the usefulness of the function then if it *allows* you to do three actions `insert`, `update` or `remove` but doesn't really allow for checking a condition. Anyway, will just use find and insert/update/remove for now.

Comment: It is supposed to be used as an atomic replacement for find+update of find+remove.